# Javascript Reverse value from scale of 1 to 10

Tags: javascript, math

Hi Lets jump straight to the example. I am good at javascript but really weak at maths. Some one guide me please:

```
num = Math.round(400/100);
//returns 4

num = Math.round(300/100);
//returns 3

num = Math.round(200/100);
//returns 2

num = Math.round(100/100);
//returns 1
```

I want this to be in reverse order...
For example if my input is `400`, I need `6` , and if my input is `300`, I need `7`.
Can some one please help me with my problem?

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
function inverse(number) {
    return (10 - (Math.round(number/100)));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
num = 10 - (num / 100)
```

10 - (400 ÷ 100) = 6
10 - (300 ÷ 100) = 7
10 - (200 ÷ 100) = 8